# Is there a function to write certain values of a dataframe to a .txt file in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file, text-files

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Index A B C D E F
1     0 0 C 0 E 0 
2     A 0 0 0 0 F
3     0 0 0 0 E 0
4     0 0 C D 0 0 
5     A B 0 0 0 0
```

Basically I would like to write the dataframe to a txt file, such that every row consists of the index and the subsequent column name only, excluding the zeroes.

For example:

```
txt file

1 C E 
2 A F 
3 E 
4 C D 
5 A B
```

The dataset is quite big, about 1k rows, 16k columns. Is there any way I can do this using a function in Pandas?

Comment: This is a v positive thread with humble people.. full support! :-)

Comment: @BlackRaven: We all are learner right? :)

Comment: oh yea very right... like the saying "you'd find a teacher amongst 3 persons in the street"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a matrix vector multiplication between the boolean matrix generated by "is this entry `"0"` or not" and the columns of the dataframe, and write it to a text file with `to_csv` (thanks to @Andreas' answer!):

```
df.ne("0").dot(df.columns + " ").str.rstrip().to_csv("text_file.txt")
```

where we right strip the spaces at the end due to the added `" "` to the last entries.

If you don't want the name `Index` appearing in the text file, you can chain a `rename_axis(index=None)` to get rid of it i.e.,

```
df.ne("0").dot(df.columns + " ").str.rstrip().rename_axis(index=None)
```

and then `to_csv` as above.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but got two errors with this
1. It repeats row 1 for the length of the dataframe 
2. My actual data has 16k columns. On writing to .txt file it produces 
``` 
A B G J K ...
```

Comment: @Radhika I didn't understand the 1st issue, does it repeat every row or only the first one? For the sample data, it doesn't repeat so I'm not sure. 2nd issue: we can use `to_csv` (borrowed from @Andreas' answer). Edited the answer.

Comment: @Radhika Maybe your data is so large that your editor wraps lines and you thought it's the same line repeating?

Comment: Ah sorry my bad, it actually worked, thank you! one question. Why do we dot multiply with (df.columns + " ")? What's the use of the space?

Comment: @Radhika So that they become `["C ", "E "]` and when taking the dot product, they sum up to give `"C E "` (if we didn't put space, they'd become `"CE"`). In short, that's kind of the separator between two column names. That's also why we `rstrip` at the end - to get rid of the space after `E`.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this (replace '0' with 0 if that are numeric 0 instead of string 0):

```
# Credits to Pygirl, made the code even better.
df.set_index('Index', inplace=True)
df = df.replace('0',np.nan)
df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(list)

# Out[79]: 
# variable
# 0    [C, E]
# 1    [A, F]
# 2       [E]
# 3    [C, D]
# 4    [A, B]
# Name: value, dtype: object
```

For the writing to text, you can use pandas as well:

```
df.to_csv('your_text_file.txt')
```

Comment: oh, the last trick is awesome, didn't think of that! (it also writes as is, `to_string` was giving `...`; I stole this and edited the answer if it is fine (with the attribute of course)).

Comment: @MustafaAydın yes its absolutely fine, I learned something new with the `.dot()`, which made your answer the leaner and therefore better one. :P

Comment: hi both, great approach... I'm learning from all of you! :-)

Comment: @Pygirl `.stack()` and groupby with `level=0`  is a nice approach. Need to wrap my head more around .stack

Comment: @Andreas: Update that as well in your answer :). I was thinking about `Matrix multiplication based answer` only then after seeing your answer `stack` came to my mind. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could replace string '0' with empty string `''`, then so some string-list-join manipulation to get the final results. Finally append each line into a text file. See code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['0','0','C','0','E','0'],
    ['A','0','0','0','0','F'],
    ['0','0','0','0','E','0'],
    ['0','0','C','D','0','0'],
    ['A','B','0','0','0','0']], columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F']
)
df = df.replace('0', '')

logfile = open('test.txt', 'a')
for i in range(len(df)):
    temp = ''.join(list(df.loc[i,:]))
    logfile.write(str(i+1) + ' ' + ' '.join(list(temp)) + '\n')
logfile.close()
```

Output test.txt

```
1 C E
2 A F
3 E
4 C D
5 A B
```